# How to add a control to WPF listview header

Tags: wpf, listview

I have a listview in a WPF app and I am currently using the click event of the listview header to sort but I would like to add a small button in each header to sort the data and ignore the rest of the header.

```
<ListView x:Name="lbxTest" behav:GridViewColumnHeaderClick.Command="{Binding SortViewCommand}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="135" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding id}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Format" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding format}" />
            <GridViewColumn Header="Date" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Date}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a `Button` to the `HeaderTemplate` of each `GridViewColumn`, e.g.:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="ID" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding id}">
    <GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Content="Sort" Command="{Binding YourSortCommand}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.HeaderTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Please refer to this blog post: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/30/handling-events-in-an-mvvm-wpf-application/

Comment: I have followed the reference and it works with a normal buttons but not the data template version.

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue. And make sure that you include a reproducible sample of your issue.